# What are some unexpected things math predicts?

Tags: big-list, math-history

Once I heard about a prophet that used math to foresaw with great accuracy many events of the humanity. Today I oddly realized the time between falling drops after washing cups fit the inverse square law.

What are some unexpected things accurately predicted by math?

Comment: I would have thought that if the drops come after closing a tap, then there is a finite amount of liquid and so a finite number of drops.

Comment: I'd say that's have to do more with natural sciences, rather than math. So you may also try asking the question at http://physics.stackexchange.com/ Though the connection of physics and math is a distinct and a rich theme for a discussion.

Comment: Was the prophet "Hari Sheldon" born 10th month of the 11,988th year of the Galactic Era?

Comment: Fun reading: http://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/MathDrama/reading/Wigner.html,  "The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences" by Eugene Wigner.

Comment: Be sure to balance the unreasonable effectiveness with the unreasonable *ineffectiveness* of math in complex systems, eg in economics: http://cje.oxfordjournals.org/content/29/6/849.abstract, in biomedicine: http://www.deirdremccloskey.com/docs/fisherian.pdf

Answer (score 10):

The angle of the wake of a body moving steadily in deep water (e.g. a ship or a duck) is always [$2\arcsin(1/3) \approx 38.9^\circ$](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/mathematics.html).

Answer (score 2):

Existence of Black Holes, Pulsars, parallel universes, worm holes.

Comment: It's not known that parallel universes or worm holes exist, so I don't think we should classify those as "accurately predicted by math" ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting article about [Mathematical Fortune-Telling](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/mathematical-fortune-telling).

Answer (score 1):

Look at Good–Turing rule, the two posts in Azimuth blog:

- [The Mathematics of Biodiversity (Part 1)](http://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/the-mathematics-of-biodiversity-part-1/)
- [The Mathematics of Biodiversity (Part 2)](http://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2012/06/24/the-mathematics-of-biodiversity-part-2/)

The puzzle itself:

> Suppose you go into the jungles of Ecuador and start collecting
>   butterflies. You count the number of butterflies of each different
>   species that you find. You get a list of numbers, something like this:
>
> 14, 10, 8, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1
>
> Puzzle: What is the chance that the next butterfly you find will
>   belong to a new species?

Answer (score 1):

A curious application from Fred Hoyle : Use the the prevalence of life forms on earth to deduce a [new resonance in the carbon-12 nucleus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropic_principle#The_nucleosynthesis_of_carbon-12).